# Did I prove correctly that for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, if $A \prec B$ and $B \prec C$, then $A \prec C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

If $A \sim B$, it means there is a one-to-one and onto function from $A$ to
$B$. If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then we will say that $B$ dominates $A$, and
write $A \precsim B$, if there is a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ that is
one-to-one. If $A \precsim B$ and $A \nsim B$, then we say that $B$ strictly
dominates $A$, and write $A \prec B$.

(b) For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, if $A \prec B$ and $B \prec C$, then $A
\prec C$.

Suppose $A \prec B$ and $B \prec C$. Then, there are one-to-one functions $f
  : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow C$. Let $h : A \rightarrow C$ be
  defined as $h = g \circ f$. Suppose $h (a_1) = h (a_2)$. Then, $g (f (a_1))
  = h (a_1) = h (a_2) = g (f (a_2))$. Since $g$ is one-to-one, $f (a_1) = f
  (a_2)$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, $a_1 = a_2$. Thus, $h$ is one-to-one, and
  $A \precsim C$.

To prove $A \nsim C$, suppose $h : A \rightarrow C$ is a one-to-one
  function. Since $A \prec B$, there is a one-to-one function $f : A
  \rightarrow B$. Let $g : Dom (f) \times C$ be defined as $g = \{ (f
  (a), c) | \exists (a, c) \in h \}$. Let $a_1 \in A$ and $a_2 \in A$. Suppose
  $a_1 \neq a_2$. Since $f$ and $h$ are one-to-one, $f (a_1) \neq f (a_2)$ and
  $h (a_1) = c_1 \neq c_2 = h (a_2)$. This means if $f (a_1) \neq f (a_2)$,
  then $g (f (a_1)) \neq g (f (a_2))$. Thus, $g$ is one-to-one. Since $f$ and
  $g$ are one-to-one, I can let $h = g \circ f$. Since $B \prec C$, $g$ is not
  onto, and I can choose some $c \in C$ such that $g (f (a)) \neq c$ for all
  $a \in A$. Thus, $h$ is not onto. Therefore, $A \prec C$.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is a subset of $\text{Im}(f) \times C$, not $\text{Dom}(f) \times C$.

You haven't shown that $g$ is actually a function (i.e., if $(x, y) \in g$ and $(z, y) \in g$, then $x = z$).

It would also be wise to put in a little more to prove that $h = g \circ f$. This is fairly easy, but not immediately obvious.

Another problem is that $g$ is only defined on $\text{Im}(f)$, not all of $B$, so it is not immediate that $B \prec C$ requires that $g$ not be onto ($g$ being onto would not directly contradict $B \prec C$).